# SQL: columns name based on variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a temporary table `aaa` that I use as an array.

```
    USE tempdb
    GO

    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..aaa') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE aaa
    CREATE TABLE aaa (
        #1 char(40),
        #2 char(40),
        #3 char(40)
    );
    insert into aaa values ('aaaa','qqqq','eeee');
    declare @sql varchar(40);
    declare @var varchar(40)='#3';
    set @sql= '(select '+@var +' from aaa)';
       print @sql;
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to store into the variable @sql the executed value of `'(select '+@var +' from aaa)'` which is: `eeee` and NOT simply the string `(select #3 from aaa)`

I know that ''this is not how SQL is supposed to work'' but after 320 questions read on SO(my history tab can prove) I'm out of ideas:)

Comment: Read about dynamic SQL: [link1](https://technet.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/ms188001(v=sql.110).aspx), [example](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1160/execute-dynamic-sql-commands-in-sql-server/)

Comment: I'm a bit confused on what you want to do.  You don't execute your SQL anywhere.  And why would you be storing a result value in a variable called `@sql`?

Comment: You *have* heard of [`EXECUTE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/t-sql/language-elements/execute-transact-sql), right?

Comment: @Jeroen Mostert yes, I heard. The problem is that I have to execute another string that contains the variable @sql. example: `exec (' insert into mytable (column) values( {the value from @sql})')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[1] `tempdb..aaa` isn't a temp table. Instead, it's nothing more than a standard table created within `tempdb` database and this means that will *deleted* when SQL Server Database Engine service is *re*started (`tempdb` database is *re*created everytime the service is started/*re*started).

[2] If you want to use a temp table then you could use following syntax:

```
CREATE TABLE #Array (RowNum INT NOT NULL, Val AS VARCHAR(10)) -- See # prefix that means a local temp table
```

or

```
CREATE TABLE ##Array (RowNum INT NOT NULL, Val AS VARCHAR(10)) -- See ## prefix that means a global temp table
```

Example:

```
INSERT #Array (RowNum, Val) VALUES (1, 'A')
INSERT #Array (RowNum, Val) VALUES (2, 'BBB')
```

and

```
SELECT ... FROM #Array WHERE RowNum = 1
```

**To see full list of all options for storing/using arrays in SQL Server see following article wrote by Erland Sommarskog** http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql.html . My personal choice will be to use XML or @table variable.

[3] Regarding approach proposed by current question: it is bad. Assuming that we have to *simulate* an array then values from that array should be stored (if we are using tables / ##temp tables / @table variables) within single column on rows (see above example) and not in different columns (Col1, Col2, etc.).

My recommendation is to read Erland Sommarskog's article and to select proper solution for your scenario.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion to use XML.  right know that seems the most doable thing

Answer (score 2):

I'm sorry to say, but the code you posted is totally unreasonable.
Instead of messing around with dynamic SQL you should simply change your table structure to contain only 2 columns - One for index and another for value:

```
CREATE TABLE aaa (
    id int identity(1, 1),
    val char(40)
)

INSERT INTO aaa VALUES
('aaaa'),
('qqqq'),
('eeee')

SELECT val
FROM aaa
WHERE Id = 3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an `sp_executesql` with an `OUTPUT` parameter to assign the scalar result:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..aaa') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE aaa
CREATE TABLE aaa (
    #1 char(40),
    #2 char(40),
    #3 char(40)
);
INSERT INTO aaa VALUES ('aaaa','qqqq','eeee');
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(40);
DECLARE @sqlStatement nvarchar(MAX);
DECLARE @var varchar(40)='#3';
SET @sqlStatement = '(SELECT '+@var +' FROM aaa)';
EXEC sp_executesql @sqlStatement, N'@sql varchar(40) OUTPUT', @sql = @sql OUTPUT;
PRINT @sql;
```

I think using a variable named `@sql` for the result is a bit confusing.

Answer (score 1):

You can create temp table (or table variable) and insert the result of your dynamic sql into.

```
create table #tmpResult (res CHAR(40));

declare @sql varchar(40);
declare @var varchar(40)='#3';
set @sql= '(select '+@var +' from aaa)';
insert #tmpResult
exec (@sql)

select * from  #tmpResult --you can easily fill @sql variable from here
```

or you can even change your dynamic sql to include this insert:

```
create table #tmpResult (res CHAR(40));

declare @sql varchar(40);
declare @var varchar(40)='#3';
set @sql= 'insert #tmpResult select '+@var +' from aaa';
exec (@sql)

select * from  #tmpResult
```